# content displaying out side of html tags for return and echo

Tags: php, html, return, echo

I know that echo will echo the content and return will return the contents for further processing. How ever, I have said function:

```
class Content{

    protected $_html = '';

    public function display_content(){
        $this->_html = 'content';
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->html;
    }
}
```

then some where I have the following:

```
$content = new Content();
<p><?php $content->disaply_content(); ?></p>
```

I get:

```
<p></p>
content
```

as the source code for the page. doesn't matter if I echo or just return, either way it displays out side the tag.

Ideas?

Comment: Is there any other code when displaying the page? 'content' should not appear at all with the supplied code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the second 'content' is coming from but note that:

```
<?php $content->display_content();?>
```

Will not display anything between the `<p>` tags. You should use:

```
<?php echo $content->display_content();?>
```

(I assume the disaply_content() was a typo in the question and not in the code).